# Why doesn't the Java compiler flag this as an error?

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have created an enumerated type in my Java webapp as a way of abstracting the procedure of adding objects to the session attributes. The idea being to precipitate an error if I try and map the wrong object type to a particular key. The enum code looks like this:

```
public enum SessionVariables
{
CURRENT_BRIEF {

    @Override
    public <Briefable> void setValue(Briefable item)
    {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put(this.toString(), item);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <Briefable> Briefable getValue()
    {
        return (Briefable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get(this.toString());
    }
};

public abstract <T> void setValue(T item);
public abstract <T> T getValue();
}
```

All fine so far, no compilation problems.

However, if I actually try and use the methods with a wrong type, no error is found by the compiler, for instance:

```
SessionVariables.CURRENT_BRIEF.setValue("String value");
```

compiles normally.

Any ideas why this is the case? Have I missed something out? I'm using Java SE 8, EE7 on a Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declared type of `CURRENT_BRIEF` is `SessionVariables`. That type has the method `<T> void setValue(T item)` and your method invocation complies with that signature.

Furthermore, when you wrote

```
public <Briefable> void setValue(Briefable item)
```

you basically restated the same thing, just naming your type parameter `Briefable`. The actual type will still be inferred from the calling context, which means that `Briefable` resolves to `String` for that invocation.